Tasmota output as dry-contacts
I'm trying to configure a tasmota flashed module in a way that I'm not sure if it's possible.
I would like that the output of each relay to be a dry-contact (controls circuit without supplying the power itself).
Something similar to the image below.
The device I'm using is a QS-WIFI-C01 and I'd like to use to control a gate motor that I do not have access to by wire or wireless. I want to use this dry contacts to hack a RF remote by soldering directly to the button,


It's not possible to have dry contacts in that module (unless maybe opening and hardware hacking that module: a risky and not recommended operation)
in fact:


N and L are to be connected to mains, and necessary for the device to work
Output L1 and Output L2 are hot terminals controlled by software or from inputs
S1 and S2 are inputs

You can always add an external 220V relay to obtain dry contacts.
Maybe this question should have been posted to electronics.stackexchange.com since it is not connected with the software inside the module
